# How to get Ant to ignore error from one target?

Tags: ant, sonarqube

I have a target, comprised of several steps, that sometimes fails.  All this target does is report to Sonar so if it fails, it's not catastrophic.  How do I get the build to succeed even if this specific target fails?

I've tried some combinations of 'condition', 'or', 'true', and 'sequential', but Ant hasn't liked any of them.

Following is what I have more or less:

```
<target name='sonar'>
    <!-- do some stuff -->
    <sonar:sonar key='key' version='version'/>
</target>
```

Comment: Did you tried with <target name="xyz" failonerror="false"> ?

Comment: Can you post the target from your Ant file?

Comment: JuanZe, there is no 'failonerror' attribute to 'target'.

Comment: If you've supplied a <taskdef> command above the <target> to tell ant where to find the sonar class path, then you can add the onerror="ignore" attribute to <taskdef>.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see this could work is using the slightly outdated yet still useful antcontrib extension. Then you can use a try/catch directive and just echo your error.
http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html